# creating a list of in raw_input

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
while True:
    line = raw_input('Enter number:')
    try:
        if line == 'done':
            break
        if int(line) == ():
            continue
    except:
        print 'invalid input'
print 'Done!'
print line
```

I would like to create a list of the numbers that are entered by the user. Can some help?

Comment: You should try to do it on your own first and then post that code here in the question. Then, you should ask a question about the code that you wrote.

Comment: You're almost there. What erroneous behavior do you notice?

Comment: I am a novice coder. Only started learning python a couple of days ago. Sorry if I am incorrectly using stackoverflow - I'm just keen to learn and develop my skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number_list = []
while True:
    line = raw_input('Enter number:')
    if line == 'done':
        break
    try:
        n = int(line)
        number_list.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        print 'invalid input'
print 'Done!'
print number_list
```

Comment: @HemeshPatel fell free to accept this answer if it solved your problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Just one more variant:

```
res = []
line = raw_input('Enter number:')
while line.lower() != 'done':
    try:
        res.append(int(line))
    except ValueError: 
        print 'Invalid input'
    line = raw_input('Enter number:')
print 'Done!'
print " ".join(map(str, res))
```